# Why is the my 'userID' initializing to 0 and not to whats being sent from PHP?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, retrofit2

Im trying to put a userId labeled as 'sno' in PHP backend into sharedPreferences and then retrieve the userId from shared preferences when trying to load Posts based on that user's userID. the userId in the debugger is shown as "0". but all other info like email name and unique id are fine according to the debugger.

Here is my request object for the login process which is the process that should store the userID in preferences.

```
RequestInterface requestInterface =             retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);
        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.LOGIN_OPERATION);
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response =    requestInterface.operation(request);
        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,true);                     editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,resp.getUser().getEmail());                    editor.putString(Constants.NAME,resp.getUser().getName());                    editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,resp.getUser().getUnique_id());
                editor.putInt(Constants.USER_ID, resp.getUser().getUserID());
                editor.apply();
                goToAllPosts();
           }
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Here is my User class:
public class User {

```
private String name;
private String email;
private String unique_id;
private String password;
private String old_password;
private String new_password;
private int userID;
private List<Post> allPostsList;
public List<Post> getAllPosts(){
    return allPostsList;
}
public void setAllPosts(List<Post> allPostsList){
this.allPostsList = allPostsList;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public String getUnique_id() {
    return unique_id;
}
public int getUserID(){
    return userID;
}
public int setUserID(int userID) { return this.userID = userID;}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public void setOld_password(String old_password) {
    this.old_password = old_password;
}
public void setNew_password(String new_password) {
    this.new_password = new_password;
}
}
```

Here is my relevant php:
index.php:

```
if ($operation == 'login') {
    if(isset($data -> user ) && !empty($data -> user) && isset($data ->       user -> email) && isset($data -> user -> password)){
      $user = $data -> user;
      $email = $user -> email;
      $password = $user -> password;
      echo $fun -> loginUser($email, $password);
    } else {
      echo $fun -> getMsgInvalidParam();
    }
```

Functions.php:

```
public function loginUser($email, $password) {
$db = $this -> db;
if (!empty($email) && !empty($password)) {
if ($db -> checkUserExist($email)) {
   $result =  $db -> checkLogin($email, $password);
   if(!$result) {
    $response["result"] = "failure";
    $response["message"] = "Invaild Login Credentials";
    return json_encode($response);
   } else {
    $response["result"] = "success";
    $response["message"] = "Login Successful";
    $response["user"] = $result;
    return json_encode($response);
   }
} else {
  $response["result"] = "failure";
  $response["message"] = "Invaild Login Credentials";
  return json_encode($response);
}
} else {
  return $this -> getMsgParamNotEmpty();
}
}
```

DBOperations.php:

```
public function checkLogin($email, $password) {
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email';
$query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
$query -> execute(array(':email' => $email));
$data = $query -> fetchObject();
$salt = $data -> salt;
$db_encrypted_password = $data -> encrypted_password;
if ($this -> verifyHash($password.$salt,$db_encrypted_password) ) {
    $user["name"] = $data -> name;
    $user["email"] = $data -> email;
    $user["unique_id"] = $data -> unique_id;
            $user["sno"] = $data -> sno;
    return $user;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
public function checkUserExist($email){
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from users WHERE email =:email';
$query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
$query -> execute(array('email' => $email));
if($query){
    $row_count = $query -> fetchColumn();
    if ($row_count == 0){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

If I haven't included something necessary to advise let me know and I can post it. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`User.userID` is holding `0` because `0` is the default value for `int`, and a real value couldn't be deserialized from your network response. Double-check that your server response is using `"userID"` for the name of the field holding this ID, and not something like `"user_id"`.